# MySQL - FIND_IN_SET , GROUP_CONCAT Problems

Tags: mysql

I'm having an issue with a query I wrote for a plugin I developed for CS:GO.

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET(total, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(total ORDER BY total DESC) FROM t_cache WHERE total != 0)) AS rank, steamID, total FROM t_cache
```

As shown in the image below, it only processes the first 129 people, and fails to `FIND_IN_SET` the rest of the users where the points != 0.

[image]

I'd like to know if there's a limit for any of the functions I used; and if it can be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the max length of the function GROUP_CONCAT with:

```
Change group_concat_max_len in the /etc/my.cnf
```

**OR only for this session**

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

**OR Global for all**

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Comment: Ah, Thank you very much. That was the issue